# Having problems with dimensions in machine learning ( Python Scikit )

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, dimensions

I am a bit new to applying machine learning, so I was trying to teach myself how to do linear regression with any kind of data on mldata.org and in the Python scikit package. I tested out the linear regression example code (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) and the code worked well with the diabetes dataset. However, I tried to use the code with other datasets, such as one about earthquakes on mldata (http://mldata.org/repository/data/viewslug/global-earthquakes/). However, I was not able to do so due to the dimension problems on there.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 55
    warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 65
    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/Documents/Programming/Python/Machine Learning/Scikit/earthquake_linear_regression.py", line 38, in <module>
    regr.fit(earthquake_X_train, earthquake_y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 371, in fit
    linalg.lstsq(X, y)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 518, in lstsq
    raise ValueError('incompatible dimensions')
ValueError: incompatible dimensions
```

How do I set up the dimensions of the data?

Size of the data:

> > > earthquake_X.shape
> > >           (59209, 1, 4)
> > >       earthquake_X_train.shape
> > >           (59189, 1)
> > >       earthquake_y_test.shape
> > >           (3, 59209)
> > >       earthquake.target.shape
> > >           (3, 59209)

The code:

```
# Code source: Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
#Experimenting with earthquake data

from sklearn.datasets.mldata import fetch_mldata
import tempfile
test_data_home = tempfile.mkdtemp()


# Load the diabetes dataset
earthquake = fetch_mldata('Global Earthquakes', data_home = test_data_home)


# Use only one feature
earthquake_X = earthquake.data[:, np.newaxis]
earthquake_X_temp = earthquake_X[:, :, 2]

# Split the data into training/testing sets
earthquake_X_train = earthquake_X_temp[:-20]
earthquake_X_test = earthquake_X_temp[-20:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
earthquake_y_train = earthquake.target[:-20]
earthquake_y_test = earthquake.target[-20:]
print "Splitting of data for preformance check completed"
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
print "Created linear regression object"
# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(earthquake_X_train, earthquake_y_train)
print "Dataset trained"
# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# The mean square error
print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((regr.predict(earthquake_X_test) - earthquake_y_test) ** 2))
# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(earthquake_X_test, earthquake_y_test))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(earthquake_X_test, earthquake_y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(earthquake_X_test, regr.predict(earthquake_X_test), color='blue',
         linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array of targets (`earthquake_y_train`) is of wrong shape. Moreover actually it's empty.

When you do

```
earthquake_y_train = earthquake.target[:-20]
```

you select all rows but last 20 among **first axis**. And, according to the data you posted, `earthquake.target` has shape `(3, 59209)`, so there are no rows to select!

But even if there were any, it'd be still an error. Why? Because first dimensions of `X` and `y` must be the same.  According to the sklearn's documentation, [LinearRegression's fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) expects `X` to be of shape [n_samples, n_features] and `y` — [n_samples, n_targets].

In order to fix it change definitions of ys to the following:

```
earthquake_y_train = earthquake.target[:, :-20].T
earthquake_y_test = earthquake.target[:, -20:].T
```

P.S. Even if you fix all these problem there's still a problem in your script: `plt.scatter` can't work with "multidimensional" ys.

Comment: How do I get around with the multidimensional problem?

Also when I tried to use the code you had, I ended up getting an error by division of zero: "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"